# How to enable visualforce page overrides on ideas?

Tags: visualforce, ideas

I've noticed a large library of visualforce components that are build aroud the ideas product (apex:vote, ideas:detailOutputLink, etc.) however I can't find a way to set up a view override for ideas like I would for normal salesforce objects (where this can be found under  > Standard Buttons and Links and press edit next to the view link)

Is it possible to set up custom visualforce pages for ideas and have them be the default view of ideas?
EDIT: I just tried adding this to the metadata and saving via the IDE but the server silently removed it on save:

```
<actionOverrides>
  <actionName>view</actionName>
  <type>visualforce</type>
  <content>IdeaView</content>
</actionOverrides>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that can be done (pursued the same path last year).  You need that black tab feature to give you the ideas controllers.

The VF components are for using on custom VF pages (what we ended up doing).  You can then make use of all the fancy ideas controllers without having to do very apex.

Comment: However that doesn't work well because the recent items sidebar still takes them to the native idea page. I'm rather disappointed with how half-baked ideas are at this point.

Comment: These were custom VF pages and I used showheader="false" and sidebar="false" in the <apex:page>.  If nothing else, you could keep the header and hide the sidebar.

Comment: While your answer isn't viable in my use case it might be for others so I've accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

I've asked salesforce partner premier support, and even had the black tab perm for "Idea Standard Controllers" enabled just in case it opened this up with no luck, and they do not know of a way that this is possible.

I've tried manually adding an actionOverrides element to the Idea object metadata but this is silently erased upon save to server.

I've also tried manually editing other standard object buttons and links URLs to get to ideas but this shows a blank page.

At this point I'm convinced this is not possible in salesforce today. Either hide the ideas tab alltogether and implement your own (although recent items is a problem in this situation) or use the standard interface appear to be the only viable answers as of today.

Comment: @ca_paterson Did you override standard ideas.Can you please post sample code

Comment: @sf.dev no, my answer specifically calls out the ways I failed to do just that. It's not possible as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ca_paterson Is it possible to build custom idea page?